# Open and close of the first 1 min bar

Tags: thinkscript

I know it's a long shot to ask here, but I am looking for a way to determine if the first 1 minute candle is red, meaning that the bar closes below the open.

To do this I simply need the open value and close value of the first one minute bar, but I haven't found a way to get the close.

Getting the open is fairly straight forward:

```
def openValue = open(period = AggregationPeriod.DAY);
```

Getting the Range of the first bar is fairly straightforward as well since we define a range (1 min) and return the high/low of that range.

If anybody can help, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, someone helped me figure it out.

```
def x = barNumber(); //bar

def RTH = getTime() >= RegularTradingStart(getYYYYMMDD()) and 

      getTime() <= RegularTradingEnd(getYYYYMMDD()); 

def TodaysOpen = if RTH and !RTH[1] 

             then open 

             else TodaysOpen[1]; 

def OpenX = if RTH and !RTH[1] 

        then x 

        else double.nan; 

def YesterdaysClose = if !RTH and RTH[1] 

                  then close[1] 

                  else YesterdaysClose[1]; 

def CloseX = if !RTH and RTH[1] 

           then x 

           else double.nan; 

def HighToday = if RTH and !RTH[1] 

            then high 

            else if RTH and high > HighToday[1] 

                 then high 

            else HighToday[1]; 

 def HighX = if high == HighToday 

        then x 

        else double.nan; 

def LowToday = if RTH and !RTH[1] 

           then low 

           else if RTH and low < LowToday[1] 

                then low 

           else LowToday[1]; 

def LowX = if low == LowToday 

       then x 

       else double.nan; 

plot OpenToday = if barNumber() >= HighestAll(OpenX) 

             then HighestAll(if isNaN(close[-1]) 

                             then TodaysOpen 

                             else double.nan) 

             else double.nan; 

 OpenToday.SetStyle(Curve.Long_Dash); 





def firstbarclose = if RTH and !RTH[1] 

             then  close

             else firstbarclose[1]; 



plot CloseBar = if barNumber() >= HighestAll(OpenX) 

             then HighestAll(if isNaN(close[-1]) 

                             then firstbarclose

                             else double.nan) 

             else double.nan; 

closebar.SetStyle(Curve.Long_Dash);
```